# Remove entry from the view after delete from the DB

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im using the following code to show table data in the index page,currently I've 
created delete inline which the user click on the delete button he get popup to confirm and click on delete is invoke action of delete which delete the entry from DB.the problme is that after i've deleted it from the DB I still see it in the UI after the modal was closed,just after I refresh the page the entry is removed ,how should I delete the entry from the UI after the ajax call get success?

```
  @model IEnumerable<TestropDownCreate.Models.TestModel>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Item</h4>
                </div>
                <div id="deleteModalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Delete

```
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SelectedGender)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SelectedGender)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    <a href="#" class="deleteLink" id="@item.ID">delete</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>


    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#deleteModal").modal("hide");  // initially hides the modal pop-up until needed

            $(".deleteLink").on("click", function () {

                $.get('@Url.Action("GetDeletePartial")', { id: $(this).prop("id") }, function (data) {
                    $("#deleteModalBody").html(data);

                    $("#deleteModal").modal("show");  // shows the modal pop-up now that we have our partial view
                });

            });
        });
 $("#deleteBtn").on("click", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: "/User/DeleteConfirmed",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:  {id: Id} ,
                    success: function (result) {
                        var id = result;

                    },


                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do the entries have an id on them? If so, then in success block use jQuery to delete them. $(entryToDelete).remove().

Comment: best and reliable way @shopia T to achieve ur functionality is to take a partialview for showing details in foreach loop and after ur delete operation just load that partial view again from jquery now that partial view will not show deleted row because it is deleted from database ...

Comment: @Archon-how do I get the entryToDelete ?this is the all code which I put in the post...

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla-can you please provide example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an id on the 'tr' in your table, such as

```
<tr id="@item.ID">
```

and then delete the tr, such as

```
$('#' + id).remove();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ,this was saved the problem ,voted up and mark answer.can you please explain how does this fix the problem ?$('#' + id) what is it the # and how all this works :) ?

Comment: Suppose your id was row-one the statement `$('#' + id)` would evaluate to `$('#row-one'). Once there's a jQuery object around that element on that page you can call .remove() to remove it from the DOM.